# Unbind <li> after click, then bind again once needed

Tags: jquery, list, live, bind, unbind

I creating a drop down. When you click "Contact", a huge contact box comes down. When I click "Close" it dissapears. This functionality works.

What I need is the unbind the list item once the form is open, but once closed, enable it again.

Code below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery("#header ul.menu li:last-child").addClass("open");

 jQuery("#header ul.menu li.open").click(function() {

  jQuery(this).unbind("click");

  jQuery("#contact").animate({marginTop:'+=426px'}, 2000);

  return false;

 });

 jQuery("#contact a#close").click(function() {

  jQuery("#contact").animate({marginTop:'-=426px'}, 2000);

  jQuery("#header ul.menu li:last-child").live("click", function() {

  });

  return false;

 });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should specify a function reference to `.unbind()` / `.bind()`.

```
function click_handler() { 
    // do something
}

jQuery("#header ul.menu li.open").click(function() {
   jQuery(this).unbind("click", click_handler);

   jQuery("#contact").animate({marginTop:'+=426px'}, 2000);

   return false;
});

// some code

jQuery("#header ul.menu li.open").bind('click', click_handler);
```